# Can't connect to mLab database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to connect to my mongodb database from URI that is hosted on mLab, but I couldn't, this error is displayed:

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [ds121090-a0.mlab.com:19490] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
__/ Connection error (MongoSocketOpenException): Exception opening socket
|____/ I/O error: connect timed out

Details:
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=ds132132190-a0.mlab.com:19490, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]
mongodb://user:xxxxx@ds132132190.mlab.com:19490/mydb
```

My localhost db works fine.

What's wrong with my server db?

Comment: Hi, if you're still having issues, can you please email support@mlab.com? We'll be better able to help troubleshoot connection issues over private email. You may also find the mLab documentation on troubleshooting connection issues helpful: http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help

Comment: Thanks @tfogo, I'll contact them.